# Scrolling effect on UITableView Header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

When I did the scrolling on the header, the tableviewcell scrolls up as if I am scrolling at the tableviewcell. I need to disable any scrolling effect on the header. When I scroll on the header, tableviewcell should not have any movement at all.

I cannot find any similar question regarding as too many questions are about the header scroll together with the tableviewcell up or header not to stick on top which is not my intention.

Comment: Do you want the UITableView header to be permemant and not scroll at all -OR- just when the user scrolls at the location of the UITableView header

Comment: The header is permanent at the top at it is. When user scrolls/swipe vertical in header, the tableview cell should not move at all. Etc: you cannot scroll at your browser url bar for the browser content to move up. You have to scroll within the browser content to view more.

Comment: You might try removing the header from the UITableView and place it above the UITableView.

Comment: How big is your header for you to be concerned for a user to place their finger on your headerview to scroll up? :\